# Existance of a fixed point of a bijective, smooth function:

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems, monotone-functions

Let $[a,b],\,\, [c,d]$ be two bounded closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$[a,b]\cap[c,d]\not=\emptyset$$ and $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ be a bijective, smooth function.

[We know that, if $[a,b]=[c,d],$ then $f$ has a fixed point.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiRlIDLv63JAhXUCI4KHZqBCaUQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFixed-point_property&usg=AFQjCNGYRyTebtf5dXniUMj-E_wnQyk6Eg)
My question is:

> If $[a,b]\not=[c,d],$ which condition(s) guaranteed the existence of a fixed point of $f$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is a fixed point then $f(x)=x$ so that $x \in [a,b]$ and $x \in [c,d]$ which is impossible if $[a,b]\cap[c,d]=\emptyset$

Comment: If $[a,b] \cap [c,d] = \varnothing$, then obviously $f$ has no fixed point.

Otherwise, let $[\alpha, \beta] = [a,b] \cap [c,d]$. Then, $f_{[\alpha,\beta]}$ has a fixed point.

Comment: @AhmedHussein: As I think, noting wrong with these conditions. Can we prove that $f[\alpha,\beta]\to[\alpha,\beta]$ is a bijection? (I think you assume this condition.)

Comment: @Ahmed Hussein Let $f:[1,3]\to [0,2]$ be defined by $f(x)=0$ when $x \in [1,2]$ and $f(x)=2(x-2)^2$ when $x \in [2,3]$. Then $f|_{[1,2]}$ has image $\{0\}$ and hence has no fixed point.

Comment: @Nex your example doesn't work; the function isn't bijective on the initial sets.

Comment: @Nilan you're right. Surjectivity isn't guaranteed. This needs some thought.

Comment: Take $[0,2]$, $[1,3]$ and $f(x)=x+1$

Comment: If $[a,b] \subset [c,d]$ and $f$ a continuous bijection, there should be a fixed point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

Smoothness and bijectivity together imply monotonicity. Distinguish the four cases
$$c<a<d<b,\quad c<a<b<d,\quad a<c<d<b,\quad a<c<b<d\ ,$$
(maybe equality signs have to be considered extra), and for each of these cases a monotonically increasing, resp., decreasing $f$ satisfying the conditions. Draw figures.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment. I could solve all cases except the case $a\lt c\lt b\lt d.$ For this part I feel, we need a more condition. Do you have any idea?